# <a> tag nested with a <table> tag is not valid in XHTML

Tags: html, email, xhtml, w3c-validation

I am coding an `html` email template. I want to make it fully legal under `XHTML` rules. There is a button in my code made it with `<table>` tag and it is linked, of course, to an URL. For that reason I added an `<a>` tag before the `<table>`. The W3C validator tool says I cannot nest these elements. I added the code to make it more understandable.

Do you have any suggestion to avoid this issue?

I appreciate your help.

```
<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#660eaa; font-size:13px; line-height:125%;" href="http://google.com/" target="_blank" >
    <table id="templateButton" style="font-size:15px; border-radius:6px; -moz-border-radius:6px; -webkit-border-radius:6px;" bgcolor="#ffd700" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding:16px 10px"><strong>Go to Google!</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</a>
```

Comment: "Do you have any suggestion to avoid this issue?" Does "don't try to write HTML email according to XHTML rules" count?

Comment: Just use a button element and style it. That's what they are for.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I always like to program as clear and formal as possible. XHTML rules are not a bother to me. Why not just meet them.

Comment: @Allen — The rules say that tables are for tabular data and that tables are not allowed inside anchors. So you can't follow them and do what you are trying to do. If you want to write proper XHTML then you should just have an anchor and style it with CSS. Then you run into the problem that email clients suck at HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an `a` tag like this.

The proper way is:

```
<table id="templateButton" style="font-size:15px; border-radius:6px; -moz-border-radius:6px; -webkit-border-radius:6px;" bgcolor="#ffd700" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
   <tr>
      <td align="center" style="padding:16px 10px">
         <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#660eaa; font-size:13px; line-height:125%;" href="http://google.com/" target="_blank" ><strong>Go to Google!</strong></a>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

You would style your `a` tag as a button, not the containers (`td` or `table`)

Also, make sure your HTML email is going to look the same or similar in the email clients you want to support.  For example the border-radius you have set, will not work in  a lot of email clients.

I encourage you to check out this site for more information regarding HTML email: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/

EDIT:
You can style the `table` and `td` by adding a background color.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check the link. There is another way to reach the same effect without using border-radius?

Comment: The only way to make border-radius consistent that I know if is to create an image version of the button.